# Problem in Executing Dynamic function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create dynamic function in postgresql function Created but it generates error while executing function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.upCal(
table_name_ text    ,   --1-- the this table name -- house1
calCol      text    ,   --2-- the column you want to change -- calendar
calConcat   text    ,   --3-- the new value will be -- concated
refCol  text    ,   --4-- with this value   -- is > 0 then new value
refVal  integer     --5-- a reference colum -- delay  
)

    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
-------

begin       


            
    execute 
              ( 'UPDATE ' || table_name_||' '   
           || 'SET   ' || quote_ident(calCol) || '=' 
    'H' 
     ||house_num  || ' S' || stage::text || ' ' ||   
    left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||    
    to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')            
    || 'WHERE ' || quote_ident(calcol)  || '>=' || quote_nullable(refCol)  ); 
        --'>='  || 0    ;
    
    END
$BODY$;
```

It generates error column "house_num" does not exist Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.upCal(
table_name_ text    ,   --1-- the this table name -- house1
calCol      text    ,   --2-- the column you want to change -- calendar
calConcat   text    ,   --3-- the new value will be -- concated
refCol  text    ,   --4-- with this value   -- is > 0 then new value
refVal  integer     --5-- a reference colum -- delay
)

    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
-------

declare
   v_sql varchar(255);

begin
    select
               'UPDATE ' || table_name_||' '
      || 'SET   ' || quote_ident(calCol)
      || '=''H'' || house_num || '' S'' || stage::text ' -- one string
      || '|| left(to_char(sdate, ''Mon''),2) || '' to '''  -- same string contd.
      || '|| to_char(sdate, ''DD'') || to_char(rdate, ''Mon-DD'')' -- still same
      || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(calcol)  || '>=' || quote_nullable(refCol)
      into v_sql ;

    raise notice '%',v_sql;

    execute v_sql;
END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: update house1 SET calendar =
 'H'||' '||house_num||' '||left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon'),2) ||' to '  || to_char(sdate, 'DD') ||to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD')
 
it works outside the function but I unable to run inside the function

Comment: Replace the execute by a "raise notice", then perhaps you will see what's wrong with your dynamic SQL.

Comment: You will need to learn quoting.  I'll update my answer but a_horse's is better.

Comment: Thank you sir It works

Comment: Ah, I've been knighted.  Or would that be "Sir"?

Comment: Please have a look at the other solution too, even more so if your problem has anything to do with the internet, or is publically accessible (SQL injection).

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to use `format()` when dealing with dynamic SQL. Additionally parameters shouldn't be concatenated into the SQL, but passed as parameters with the `USING` clause. You can also ne

```
execute format($dyn$ 
               UPDATE %I 
                SET %I = concat('H', $1, ' S', $2, ' ', $2, ' ', $3, ' to ', $4, $5) 
               WHERE %I >= %I
               $dyn$, table_name, calCol, calCol, refcol)
   using house_num, 
         stage, 
         left(to_char(sdate, 'Mon', 2)), 
         to_char(sdate, 'DD'), 
         to_char(rdate, 'Mon-DD';
```

The `%I` placeholder will properly deal with quoting identifiers. Passing actual values through the `USING` clause will make sure you have no trouble with quoting literals.

If you still get errors, put the generated SQL into a variable and print it before running it:

```
 l_stmt := format(...);
 raise notice 'SQL: %', l_stmt;
 execute l_stmt
   using ....;
```